# Connection to xamm server failed in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am using php to connect my database using xampp server.The data is displayed in json format using the php code.Now i want to display this 
data in android app in list view. 
But the app display nothing , maybe i cannot connect database to the app.
My php code is working .

Logcat show this error -

> fail to open file: No such file or directory Connect to /10.0.2.2:80
>   timed out .

MainActivity class-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 

ListView ClubListView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String HttpURL = "http://10.0.2.2/db1/display.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ClubListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ClubFormListView);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar1);

    new ParseJSonDataClass(this).execute();
}

private class ParseJSonDataClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Context context;
    String FinalJSonResult;
    List<Player> ClubList;

    public ParseJSonDataClass(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = newHttpServiceClass(HttpURL);

        try {
            httpServiceClass.ExecuteGetRequest();

            if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();

                if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    try {

                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonResult);
                        JSONObject jsonObject;
                        Player player;

                        ClubList = new ArrayList<Player>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            player = new Player();

                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            player.Player_Name=
                             jsonObject.getString("Name");

                            player.Player_Club = 
                            jsonObject.getString("ClubName");

                            ClubList.add(player);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {

     Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceClass.getErrorMessage(),
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ClubListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (ClubList != null) {

            ListsAdapter adapter = new ListsAdapter(ClubList, context);
            ClubListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
      }
      }
```

Logcat

```
fail to open file: No such file or directory
Connect to /10.0.2.2:80 timed out 
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.
openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
at com.example.phpdata.HttpServiceClass.executeRequest
(HttpServiceClass.java:108)
 at com.example.phpdata.HttpServiceClass.ExecuteGetRequest
(HttpServiceClass.java:82)
 com.example.phpdata.MainActivity$ParseJSonDataClass.doInBackground
 (MainActivity.java:65)
 (MainActivity.java:43)  
 (MainActivity.java:101)
```

Comment: may be your db1/display.php is not configured properly and make sure that your phone or emulator and server pc are in same network. did u enable the internet permission in manifest?. thank you

Comment: what happen if you try `http://10.0.2.2/db1/display.php` with a browser on your Android device ?

Comment: Log the value for FinalJSonResult. What is it ? Start Debugging and check it out.

Comment: @VarmaLanke Yes i enabled the internet permission.How do i check if my pc and emulator are on same network?

Comment: @bwt when i try http://10.0.2.2 from browser on my emulator , it gives me the same Json values  , as my php code did in my pc browser

Comment: @JaiminModi log value of FinalJSonResult {"success":1,"data":[{"ID":101,"name":"C.R","club":"Juventus"},{"ID":102,"name":"S.R","club":"R.M"},{"ID":103,"name":"M.V","club":"R.M"}]}

Comment: @JaiminModi it also gives me this exception  - org.json.JSONException: Value {"success":1,"data":[{"ID":101,"name":"C.R","club":"Juventus"},{"ID":102,"name":"S.R","club":"R.M"},{"ID":103,"name":"M.V","club":"R.M"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)

Comment: Hello Bro, You are trying to convert a JSONObject to JSONArray. That's why the error is coming. Create your model or pojo class properly according to your response. You can create it online here : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @JaiminModi Can you tell me how to do it , I am new doing this type of stuff for first time , so i have no idea how to fix it . Thanks  for your response :)

Comment: Ya Sure, first visit jsonschema2pojo.org Then, paste your response over there. Select radio buttons there : 1. JAVA, 2. JSON, 3. Gson. Check "Include Getters and Setters" and then click Preview. Your model class will be ready. If you don't have idea about GSON for parsing then first learn about Gson and then try this thing. So, while you will use Gson, you need not to do json.getString and other stuff manually. You can find it's value from your model class's variables.

Comment: @JaiminModi Ok I have generated the preview , what to do next?

Comment: @user10050258 Add that class in your Android Studio and use it. Here is nice example : https://www.journaldev.com/2321/gson-example-tutorial-parse-json Please understood it properly and then implement.

Comment: @JaiminModi .it's working now , thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user10050258 ya welcome, please upvote comments dude.